# how do you save csv file to a user defined directory in python

Tags: python, csv

I need to read csv file to data frame and write it to folder name with given file name

for example:

user enter the path of the csv file, user enters the output path name, I read the csv file in data frame write the output of the csv to a user defined folder/filename.

I tried this:

```
##read the file
excel_path = input('Enter excel file path:')
#default output directory defined
default_save_path = './Out/'
if(not os.path.isfile(excel_path)):
        print('File does not  exist ! Enter valid file.')
#user enters the name of the folder name the files need to be saved
output_folder_name = input('Enter name of Folder to which the files to be saved:')
output_path = default_save_path + '/' + output_folder_name
createDirIfNotExists(output_path)
df = pd.read_csv(excel_path)



date = datetime.now().strftime("%Y_%m_%d-%I_%M_%S_%p")
df.to_csv(output_path+"_"+date+'.csv', encoding='utf-8')
```

the file is not written in ./out directory. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you get when you do print(output_path+"_"+date+'.csv') ?

Comment: @zvxf let say I put "nt", the output would be nt_2022_01_25-10_17_15_AM.csv

Comment: I would recommend using `os.path.join(default_save_path, output_folder_name)` instead of doing `default_save_path + '/' + output_folder_name`.

Comment: I think you need one more `'/'` in the last line after output_path